# How to find an Inverse for $Y=1-\frac{1}3(2e^{-X}+e^{-5X})$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

I would like to find an inverse for:

$Y=1-\frac{1}3(2e^{-X}+e^{-5X})$

I have tried a change of variable $Z=e^{-X}$ but I get to a equation that I cannot solve either.

Comment: have you proved that an inverse exists?

Comment: It is a decreasing function. Hence the inverse exists.

Comment: Is it $\frac13(\cdots)$ or $\frac1{3(\cdots)}$?

Comment: @rubik I edited to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

the only idea I have is multiplying by $e^x$ then we have $$-3(y-1)e^x=2+e^{-4x}$$ and multiplying by $$e^{4x}$$ we get
$$-3(y-1)e^{5x}=2e^{4x}+1$$ let $t=e^x$ then we have
$$-3(y-1)t^5=2t^4+1$$

Comment: Ok, but how can I find $t$ as a function of $y$?

Comment: you must solve this equation for $t$, but I think it is impossible

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner,  Ok, thank you.